# Why do 6+ month old unanswered questions from certain specific date ranges suddenly reappear in batches on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, bump

I've noticed that occasionally I will suddenly start seeing bursts of old, unanswered questions from the same 2 - 3 day span on the SO tags I follow. Many of the questions are more than 6 months old. Most of them reappear because they have been edited by the same user. What is the reason for this? Do admins occasionally go back and reactivate old unanswered questions to see if they will be answered? And if they do, why are they always from a specific 2 - 3 day period?

Comment: " because they have been edited by the same user"... So are you asking why rep farmers edit batches of old similar questions at a time?

Comment: Can regular users edit quesitons? I assumed only admins could, but I am pretty new to the site.

Comment: You may want to read help https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange ...   (summary "yes")

Comment: I see, it is still curious that they would choose such a specific date range. It was so sudden and so specific that it made me wonder if it was automated w/ bots.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Don't you mean https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing?

Comment: I found that page eventually, but he made me work for it. Ugh.  ;p  I thought this site was for getting people to do things for you

Comment: Could you raise a moderator flag on one of those posts, explaining your observations please? I'd like to investigate if there is possible gaming going on (badge hunting for example).

Comment: If a person continuously editing posts only bump it into home page, do raise a custom mod flag as said by @MartijnPieters. It is gaming the system and appropriate action should be taken against that person.

Comment: Ok - let me go see if I can find them. Shouldn't be difficult as they were almost all from the same user. I just assumed it was an automated admin bot or something. Heh.

Comment: are you sure that all the edits are not made to update the syntax in order to match with the current technology version or to fix broken link?

Comment: Ah, that's a user cleaning up a tag. I don't think they meant to pick a specific date range, I think they are just slogging through *all* the posts on the tag and finding where they are used incorrectly, and is doing so in date order.

Comment: Fair enough. I was assuming it was an admin, but was very confused why so many posts from feb 20-23 were being edited. There were like 10 of them on my feed at one point.

Comment: @diopside: look for Feb 19th soon. Then 18th. They started with posts from June in June and have been busy ever since.

Comment: Wow hats off to that...   I can't say I envy the work but its good someone does it!

Comment: @diopside "_I thought this site was for getting people to do things for you_" You (hopefully, probably) didn't mean it quite so bluntly, but that's almost exactly what this site is **not** for! It's main purpose is to allow users to _help_ others to do things themselves, and to be a repository of such help.

Comment: That was sarcasm...  should have added the  /s  tag  :-P

Comment: Although it is apparently a common sentiment judging from some of the questions I see every day! Hah. Some of it I chalk up to language barriers, and people not knowing how to word things 'politely' so it sounds like they are making demands. But many people are definitely making demands...

Comment: @diopside I _suspected_ it might have been (hence the _hopefully/probably_ bit) but thought it worth responding to _just to be safe_...

Comment: @MartijnPieters is badge hunting outlawed?  I have in the past made a point of visiting SO every day just to get the relevant gold badge - if SO doesn't want to encourage a particular behaviour (like Archaeology), it shouldn't award badges for it.

Comment: @MartinBonner: it's fine if the edits are constructive. If, however, someone is removing a space here and adding a space there, just to get a badge... We encourage *quality* actions, if you are obviously just churning the edits for the badge then that's not okay.

Comment: By any chance, are you referring to my recent efforts? cc @MartijnPieters

Comment: @TylerH: nope, not you.

Answer (score 19):

Badges.

The Archaeologist Badge is awarded to people who edit posts > 6 months old. For instance, the Silver badge is awarded once you have edited 100 posts over 6 months old.

If I was trying to get this badge, I would probably do a search for posts 6 months old, and start working backwards finding posts that need editing. Given the number of posts arriving each day, it is reasonable that I would get bored before I have gone further back than say 6months+1-2 days.

Comment: No, tag-cleaning. See Martijn Pieters's comment above.

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive though - and the question is a general "why does this happen", rather than a specific instance, so this is a valid answer to the general case

Comment: In this *specific case*, no, this is not a case of badge hunting. The edits don't qualify towards the badge, and they started with posts that were quite recent at the time, but working their way backwards.

Comment: @mjs If they are just cleaning up the tags [that does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126624/do-tag-edits-count-for-archaeologist)